# Increasing the limit on HTML element nesting in Firebug?

Tags: html, firefox, firebug

I have a page with deeply-nested HTML elements generated from a framework. I would like to inspect it with Firebug.
At a certain depth Firebug no longer displays the element contents.

The simplest way to reproduce the issue is with this perl snippet. It will create 100 nested divs, with text every 10.

```
foreach $i (1 .. 100) {
  print "<div id=\"$i\">\n";
  print $i if (0 == ($i % 10));
}
print "</div>\n" x 100;
```

Using Firebug to inspect the text "100", at div 96 instead of

```
<div id="96">
  ... contents ...
```

there is only

```
<div ="">
```

Is it possible to increase the depth that Firebug can cope with?

Versions are Windows Firefox 7.0.1 with Firebug 1.8.3

The "inspect element" in Chrome works fine with this example, as does F12 inspection in Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: I've never had this problem before. Any framework with over 96 nested elements is a lousy one, get rid of it. Anyway, sounds like a technical limitation, so I doubt there's a solution on FireBug's side.

Comment: Agree, I don't think that it's a Firebug's fault. You should retag your question and at least add a "perl" tag.

Comment: I have amended the question to make it clearer that the perl is merely the simplest way to create a test case, and that other browser inspectors work fine.

Comment: According to [this](http://helephant.com/2007/08/04/extreme-nesting-experiment-in-ie-and-firefox/), firefox can support unto a million nested divs, so it likely is an issue with Firebug.

Comment: I agree with @Truth - nesting your elements that deeply is a sign of something very wrong. Even if you can get it to work in Firebug, this is still going to cause performance issues with your CSS.

Comment: Changing the web framework is in the development timeline, but the existing web framework will be in place for weeks if not months.

Comment: Drop Firebug, use Chrome Developer Tools. And fill Firebug bug report.

Comment: Using Command+U (ctrl if win) and checking the source-code shows the code like it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, as mentioned in some comments already: what framework generates that kind of depth? :) Best try to solve that.

Back to your question, I would speculate the answer to your question is that the depth is determined by Firefox, not Firebug, and thus cannot be changed.

The FB addon is open source. I had never looked at it before, but glancing over [this source file](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.9/content/firebug/html/insideOutBox.js) it seems the `aria-expanded` attribute is used to create trees. Speculating even more, based on [this aria attribute](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-valuemax) I would guess that Firefox has that value-max set somewhere around 100.

Funny thing to note by the way, if I keep expanding in Firebug with the 'right' arrow key it does seem to expand all the way down to the 100th div: you can see this in the bar just above the html (and just below the {Console, Html, ...} bar). It's just the collapse/expand visualization that stops at some max depth.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous comment, I would suggest trying not to use that framework, or amending it.